# add Label to the bottom of WebView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiwebview, xcode5

I have a app that I build using xib in Interface Builder. In my view on Interface Builder,  i have a WebView and  has toolbar at the bottom. In the following image, the two labels is  on the toolbar at the bottom 
[image]

but when i run the app on simulator the label appears above in UIWEBVIEW . How can I fix that?

[image]

if i don't add the toolbar and just add the label at the bottom then still this problem comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because UILabel cannot be a UIToolBar's subview, you must add an UIView in your UIToolBar and set an UILabel as a view's subview:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you are design your XIB in 3.5 inch and you are running it in 4.0 inch simulator. So what I suggest, you need to do two very simple steps.

1. Un-tick auto layout option

[image]

2. just set the autoSizing. Select the super view of your label or the label (if your label directly added on view) and set same as below 
   [image]